# java full gc taking too long

Tags: java, performance, garbage-collection

I have a Java client which consumes a large amount of data from a server.  If the client does not keep up with the data stream at a fast enough rate, the server disconnects the socket connection.  My client gets disconnected a few times per day.  I ran jconsole to see the memory usage, and the heap space graph looks like a fairly well defined sawtooth pattern, oscillating between about 0.5GB and 1.8GB (2GB of heap space is allocated).  But every time I get disconnected is during a full GC (but not on every full GC).  I see the full GC takes a bit over 1 second on average.  Depending on the time of day, full GC happens as often as every 5 minutes when busy, or up to 30 minutes can go by in between full GCs during the slow periods.

I suspect if I can reduce the full GC time, the client will be able to better keep up with the incoming data, but I do not have much experience with GC tuning.  Does anyone have some insight on if this might be a good idea, and how to do it?  Or is there an alternative idea which may work as well?

** UPDATE **
I used -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC and it improved, but I still got disconnected during the very busy moments.  So I increased the heap allocation to 3GB to help weather through the busy moments and it seems to be chugging along pretty well now, but it's only been 1 day without a disconnection.  Maybe if I get some time I will go through and try to reduce the amount of garbage created which I'm confident will help as well.  Thanks for all the suggestions.

Comment: Can you change the time out on the connection?

Comment: Increase heap size to 4GB and observe the patterns of disconnection and Full GC time period.

Comment: Changing the disconnect threshold is not an option unfortunately

Comment: One thing I've seen in Java server apps is using a new object for each network read and copy. Try changing to using a single byte array allocation for reads and copy the bytes from there to other persistent byte arrays. Of course, one of my pet peeves with Java is that most people use libraries of code which make doing these changes effectively impossible as it is buried too deeply.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Full GC could take very long to complete, and is not that easy to tune.

One way to (easily) tune it is to increase the heap space - generally speaking, double the heap space can double the interval between two GCs, but will double the time consumed by a GC. If the program you are running has very clear usage patterns, maybe you can consider increase the heap space to make the interval so large that you can guarantee to have some idle time to try to make the system perform a GC. On the other hand, following this logic, if the heap is small a full garbage collection will finish in a instant, but that seems like inviting more troubles than helping.

Also, `-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC` might help since it will try to perform the GC operations concurrently (not stopping your program; see [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/gc-tuning-6-140523.html#cms)).

[Here's](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Java-GC-Azul-C4) a very nice talk by Til Gene (CTO of Azul systems, maker of high performance JVM, and published several GC algos), about GC in JVM in general.

Answer (score 5):

It is not easy to tune away the Full GC.  A much better approach is to produce less garbage.  Producing less garbage reduces pressure on the collection to pass objects into the tenured space where they are more expensive to collect.

I suggest you use a memory profiler to

- reduce the amount of garbage produced.  In many applications this can be reduce by a factor of 2 - 10x relatively easily.
- reduce the size of the objects you are creating e.g. use primitive and smaller datatypes like double instead of BigDecimal.
- recycle mutable object instead of discarding them.
- retain less data on the client if you can.

By reducing the amount of garbage you create, objects are more likely to die in the eden, or survivor spaces meaning you have far less Full collections, which can be shorter as well.

Don't take it for granted you have to live with lots of collections, in extreme cases you can avoid it almost completely http://vanillajava.blogspot.ro/2011/06/how-to-avoid-garbage-collection.html

Comment: I agree with creating less garbage. Also, with escape analysis if you keep all references inside the function they'll get collected on function exit. Or they should.

Comment: @ZanLynx Yes they should, but I won't assume they do. ;) In fact if you can find examples of where this works, let me know. Escape analysis places the object on the stack instead of the heap so it is not collected as such.

Answer (score 2):

Take out calls to Runtime.getRuntime().gc() - When garbage collection is triggered manually it either does nothing or it does a full stop-the-world garbage collection.  You want incremental GC to happen.

Have you tried using the server jvm from a jdk install?  It changes a bunch of the default configuration settings (including garbage collection) and is easy to try - just add -server to your java command.

```
java -server
```

What is all the garbage that gets created?  Can you generate less of it?  Where possible, try to use the valueOf methods.  By using less memory you'll save yourself time in gc AND in memory allocation.